# Solr Facet Query

Tags: lucene, solr

I have a schema which has field Polarity  which is of type "text" and has three values 0,1,-1 and CreatedAt which is of type "date".

How can I get count of each polarity based on dates. For example, it gives the output that on 5/1/2011 there were 10 counts of 0, 10 counts of 1 and 10 counts of -1

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

> http://192.168.0.10:8080/solr/your_repository/select?q=date:20110105&facet=true&facet.limit=10&facet.field=Polarity

Comment: But this query would give me the facet for a particular day only. I would like to have the count per day for a range of days in one query

Comment: I don't think you can get what you are staying, I don't think it can be called a facet anymore, it would be an array of facets. The only thing I can see is to possibly change to "date:[20110105 TO 20110109]" but it won't be per day, it will be for the period.

Answer (score 0):

A little late but may help others looking for an answer.

I would suggest check for Solr [pivots](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HierarchicalFaceting#Pivot_Facets) for this kind of hierarchical faceting.
You can facet on the dates and the polarity as secondary facet to get results within the date.