# solr query with date faceting parameters and field grouping

Tags: solr, faceted-search, facet, solr4

I am wondering if there's a way to achieve what I want. I did see a post similar to this but without any answers. [Solr Facet Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935066/solr-facet-query)
Basically, I have a field named msg_type that can have only three values log, warnings and errors. What I want is a count of each of these three categories per month starting from one year before.
    E.g.
    July 2012: Logs = 20, Warnings = 30, Errors = 40
    August 2012 Logs = 22, Warnings = 32, Errors = 50
    ...

Can someone let me know the query I should use for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest check for Solr [pivots](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HierarchicalFaceting#Pivot_Facets) for this kind of hierarchical faceting.

This will allow you to facet on Dates and then on the error types giving individual counts for each.

e.g. `facet.pivot = date,error_type`

Response should be as below

```
date
    error - 1
    warning - 2
    info - 3
date ......
```